# How can I ascertain and test SQL injection vunerabilities on this login code?

Tags: php, mysql, security

I know about the "little bobby tables" scenario and was just wondering if this code is vulnerable to such SQL injections.

<sup>I am fairly new to PHP and am curious about this.</sup>

**My code for a login script:**

```
<?php
  # session
  session_start();

  # get the variables from login.php
  $userid = $_POST["userid"];
  $pword = $_POST["pword"];

  mysql_real_escape_string($userid);
  mysql_real_escape_string($pword);

  # query the DB 
  $query = mysql_query ("
    SELECT username 
    FROM login 
    WHERE username = '$userid' 
    AND pword = '$pword';
  ");

  if ($query === FALSE) {
    die('There has been an error.<br><br> Please re-enter your Login Details on the <b><a href="login.php">Login</a></b> Page.<br><br>');
  }

  $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
  $record = $result['username'] ;

  # valid login
  # check if session is operational, if so redirect the user
  # to the correct page
  if ($record != null) {
    $_SESSION['login'] = true;
    header( 'Location: index.php' ) ;
  }

  # invalid login
  else if ($record == null) {
    echo "
    We cant find you on the system.
    <br/>
    Please return to the <b><a href='login.php'>Login</a></b> page and ensure that 
    <br/>
    you have entered your details correctly.
    <br><br>
    <b>Warning</b>: You willl be redirected  back to the Login Page 
    <br> in <b> <span id='counter'>10</span> Second(s)</b>";
  }
?>
```

The main reason for asking this is that when I login inputting:

```
'user'); DROP TABLE Login;--'
```

it doesn’t drop the table.

**My question is:** Am I typing in the right SQL injection?

Comment: the single quotes around the sql are not used, theyre only there for the purpose of this question

Answer (score 6):

This is vulnerable:

```
mysql_real_escape_string($userid);
mysql_real_escape_string($pword);
```

does not return the variable. Use:

```
$userid = mysql_real_escape_string($userid);
$pword = mysql_real_escape_string($pword);
```

If you really want to take care of all vulnerable SQL injections try to move to PDO. [Here is a nice tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers)

Comment: Oops, I didn't notice this in my answer. To add to this one though, you are not dropping the table because the `mysql_*` family of functions only execute a single statement, not multiple ones, so anything after the `;` in your statement (e.g. the `DROP TABLE`) is ignored.

Comment: @slugonamission so I was not wrong

Comment: yes, but to get to last `;` it will have to pass `$userid` and `$pword` right?

Comment: @EaterOfCorpses - I never said you were?

Comment: @slugonamission See my answer I posted just at the same time as you lol

Comment: @MihaiIorga Yep,

Comment: @MihaiIorga - oh yes, it is still very much vulnerable, but the OP was was asking why his `user'); DROP TABLE Login;--` didn't drop the table. Something along the lines of `' OR ''='` for both the username and password would allow for passwordless login.

Comment: Exactly what was in my mind :)

Comment: @EaterOfCorpses - but...mine was about a minute earlier. I still upvoted yours since it's still technically correct :P

Comment: You answered at 09:57:15 :)

Comment: My browser says 9:58 vs 9:59 ;)

Comment: @slugonamission my at the same time = time +/- `new DateInterval('PT30S')`

Answer (score 2):

The injection doesn't work because `mysql_query` only does the first query till the `;` then it stops so its not possible that way, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: That's right, but the code is vulnerable to to other SQL injection attacks.